# логирование исключение (exceptions) в Java

Tags: java-ee, исключения, log4j

Пишу небольшое веб приложение с бд. В слое DAO выполняю CRUD операции и вместо стандартного Exception кидаю свой.

```
@Override
    protected void preparedStatementForInsert(PreparedStatement statement, User object) throws PersistException {
        try {
            statement.setString(1, object.getLogin());
            statement.setString(2, object.getPassword());
            statement.setString(3, object.getEmail());
            statement.setDouble(4, object.getCashAmount());
            statement.setString(5, object.getPhone());
            statement.setDate(6, (Date) object.getBirth());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new PersistException("Cannot insert user data", e);
        }
    }
```

Дальше в слое сервиса я оборачиваю dao exceptions.

```
 @Override
    public boolean create(User newInstance) throws  ServiceException {

        try {

            dao = factory.getDao(User.class);
            daoAuthority = factory.getDao(Authority.class);
           //проверка данных из JSP формы и выбрасывание исключения 
            if (isUserExists(newInstance)) {
                throw new UserServiceException("This login exists in DB", UserServiceException.LOGIN_DUPLICATE);
            }

            Authority authority = new Authority();
            authority.setLogin(newInstance);
            authority.setPassword(newInstance.getPassword());

            factory.setAutoCommit(false);
            dao.create(newInstance);
            daoAuthority.create(authority);
            factory.commit();
            factory.setAutoCommit(true);

        } catch (PersistException e) {
           throw new ServiceException(e);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Дальше я буду обрабатывать данные ошибки в классе, взаимодействующем с JSP

```
public class RegistrationPage implements ActionCommand {

    static final String LOGIN = "Sorry, this login is taken";
    static final String BIRTH = "Enter a correct birthday";
    static final String EMAIL = "Enter valid email";

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws PersistException {
......
 return new ActionForward("/main.do", true);
}
```

Вопрос состоит в следующем. Где мне логировать exception? Это делать в слое дао или в сервисе или в классе, который будет взаимодествовать с JSP?

Я вычитал, что нежелательно использовать данный анти паттерн: логирование и пробрасывание exception. Надо делать что-то одно.

```
catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
LOG.error("Blah", e);
throw new MyServiceException("Blah", e);
}
```

UPD: Мне нельзя использовать фреймворки. Только голые servlet/jsp/jdbc

Comment: Логирование - это сквозная функциональность, её лучше вынести в аспект и не "пачкать" ею основную логику.

Comment: Я не силен в программирование. По - моему данную функциональность предоставляет spring фреймворк, но я, к сожалению, не могу его использовать.

Comment: Java EE 6, включающий JSR 318, с нами с 2009-го года. Так что любой современный сервер приложений умеет работать с интерцепторами.